Laravel File system auth
I try build a Laravel authentication application that is based on file system storage and in database based way parallel.
I made a method, like this:
    private function fileAuth(array $credentials): void
    {
        $userFileName = config('backup_values.backup_path') . $credentials['email'] . '.json';
        $user = AuthFileUtils::readFile($userFileName);
        if (Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->password)) {
            $loggedInUser = new User();
            foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
                $loggedInUser->{$key} = $value;
            };
            Auth::guard('web')->login($loggedInUser);
        } else {
            RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
            ]);
        }
    }

I try use Auth::guard('web')->login($loggedInUser) method but it call database query.
Do I need create custom provider? How can I make it in a simply way?
Please help me.

the configuration to use database system or any other one, is in the config file config/auth.php and decided by the provider configured there

I know there is an auth.php. Can you send me a sample provider code? Do I need a guard implementation?

it's so complicated and unconventional that no one bothered to do it. Your provider needs just to implement the interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider and declare those methods. https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authentication#the-user-provider-contract

I made a custom provider and I registered it like this:
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Vite;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    public function boot(): void
    {
        Vite::prefetch(concurrency: 3);

        Auth::provider('custom', function ($app, array $config) {
            return new CustomUserProvider();
        });
    }
}

The custom provider looks like this:
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\utils\AuthFileUtils;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class CustomUserProvider implements UserProvider
{

    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {

    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, #[\SensitiveParameter] $token)
    {

    }

    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, #[\SensitiveParameter] $token)
    {

    }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(#[\SensitiveParameter] array $credentials)
    {
        $fileName = config('backup_values.backup_path') . $credentials['email'] . '.json';
        $userFromFile = AuthFileUtils::readFile($fileName);
        $user = new User();
        foreach ($userFromFile as $key => $value) {
            $user->$key = $value;
        }
        return $user;
    }

    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, #[\SensitiveParameter] array $credentials)
    {
        $result = Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->getAuthPassword());
        return $result;
    }

    public function rehashPasswordIfRequired(Authenticatable $user, #[\SensitiveParameter] array $credentials, bool $force = false)
    {
        $result = $credentials['password'];
        return hash::make($result);
    }
}

And I set it in auth.php like this:
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\User::class),
        ],
    ],


But the user not logged in. How can I use it? The methods called in CustomUserProvider and I think result is good, but session not redirected to dashboard.

I implemented the retrieveById method in my CustomUserProvider:
    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        $dirPath = config('backup_values.backup_path');
        $files = scandir($dirPath);
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $filePath = $dirPath . '/' . $file;
            if (is_file($filePath)) {
                try {
                    $user = AuthFileUtils::readFile($filePath);
                    if ($user->id == $identifier) {
                        $locatedUser = new User();
                        foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
                            $locatedUser->{$key} = $value;
                        }
                        return $locatedUser;
                    }
                } catch (\Exception $e) {

                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

And it looks like work now.
